# how can ı do that moving subfolder to top folder

Tags: windows, cmd

Can I do this with cmd?

for example

c:\a\a1\qw.exe   =>  c:\a1\qw.exe  like that

I have many directories like that so I want to learn how can I do this in windows?

I want to move many folders in one command

Thank you for your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combine `move` with two `for /d` loops:

```
for /d %i in (?) do for /d %j in ("%i\*.*") do move "%j" .
```

The first loop will find all directories with a single character (`?` will match `a`, `b`) below the current directory. The second loop will find all directories (`*.*` will match everything) in these directories and move it to the current directory.

Replace `?` by `*.*` if you don't have single letter directories. But be warned: do **not** run this in `C:\`, or it will attempt to move all folders out of the `Windows` and `Program Files` directory.

Answer (score 0):

**The Move Command** allows users to transfer files or directories from one directory to another, or from one drive to another.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/move

```
move /?
```

**Example of Move Command**

To move the files of c:\windows\test to the test directory in the root directory, this is of course assuming you have the Windows\test directory.

```
move c:\windows\test\*.* c:\test
```

**Powershell Move-Item**

The Move-Item cmdlet moves an item, including its properties, contents, and child items, from one location to another location. The locations must be supported by the same provider. For example, it can move a file or subdirectory from one directory to another or move a registry subkey from one key to another. When you move an item, it is added to the new location and deleted from its original location.

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/729f90e2-4c1d-445d-ad72-6f752a3d7d24/powershell-move-folder-and-subfolders

**Example Using PowerShell Move-Item**

```
$parentpath = "C:\Temp"
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $parentpath -Filter "*.txt" -Recurse
Set-Location $parentpath

New-Item -Name "test" -ItemType Directory -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
Set-Location .\test

foreach ($file in $files)
{
   $destination = New-Item -ItemType directory -Name $(split-path $file.Directory -Leaf) -erroraction 'silentlycontinue'
   $file | Move-Item -Destination  $destination
}
```

**Bit-Transfer**

My Bit-Transfer script is here. I would place it here for you, but some start complaining that I copied my own script to this post.

[backup www directory from local to network drive powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70204002/backup-www-directory-from-local-to-network-drive-powershell/70205111#70205111)

**Here You Go Using WhatIf** -- 'd:\deneme\a\a1', 'd:\deneme\b\b1', 'd:\deneme\c\c1' one level up 'd:\deneme\a1', 'd:\deneme\b1', 'd:\deneme\c1'

```
$paths = "d:\deneme\a\a1", "d:\deneme\b\b1", "d:\deneme\c\c1"

ForEach($path in $paths) {
    $path = $path.ToString()
    $up = $path.Substring(0, $path.lastIndexOf('\'))
    #Move-Item -Path $path -Destination $up -force -Verbose
    Move-Item -Path $path -Destination $up -WhatIf

}
```